# Jitsi JWT token validation using Public Key Validation

Tags: jwt, jitsi, jitsi-meet, lib-jitsi-meet

I am implementing Public Key Validation mechanism to validate JWT token generated using RSA256 algo while joining jitsi call

I am putting kid 'xyz' in token header while generating token and my token payload structure is shown below

```
{
  "context": {
    "user": {
      "avatar": "<avatar URL>",
      "name": "me",
      "email": "me@example.com"
    }
  },
  "aud": "jitsi-meet.xyz.com",
  "iss": "eyJSb2xlIjoiQWRtaW4iLCJJc3N1ZXIiOiJJc3N1ZXIiLCJVc2Vybm",
  "sub": "*",
  "room": "*",
  "exp": 1699339600
}
```

and I also have public key URL which have configured in 'asap_key_server' property the URL looks like this

https:///public/key/< sha256() of the 'kid' field (xyz)>.pem
and this URL provides public key in JSON format

```
{
"keys": [
  {
    "alg": "RS256",
    "kty": "RSA",
    "use": "sig",
    "kid": "xyz"
    "n": "yeNlzlub94YgerT030codqEztjfU_S6X4DbDA_iVKkjAWtYfPHDzz_sPCT1Axz6isZdf3lHpq_gYX4Sz-cbe4rjmigxUxr-FgKHQy3HeCdK6hNq9ASQvMK9LBOpXDNn7mei6RZWom4wo3CMvvsY1w8tjtfLb-yQwJPltHxShZq5-ihC9irpLI9xEBTgG12q5lGIFPhTl_7inA1PFK97LuSLnTJzW0bj096v_TMDg7pOWm_zHtF53qbVsI0e3v5nmdKXdFf9BjIARRfVrbxVxiZHjU6zL6jY5QJdh1QCmENoejj_ytspMmGW7yMRxzUqgxcAqOBpVm0b-_mW3HoBdjQ",
    "e": "AQAB"
  }
]}
```

but when I am trying to join the call using my JWT token. I am unable to join, But there is no error in jitsi logs. Not sure, what am I doing wrong. I have checked my JWT token against this public key URL its working fine when I check it manually against the public key URL